# WSL Ubuntu 18.04 : where is $PATH modified at startup?

Tags: bash, environment-variables, bashrc

In summary, there are entries in my `$PATH` that i don't know where they are added. Help!

My general question is: At which places is my `$PATH` variable modified when starting up a terminal?
My specific question is, where the `/usr/local/games` folder is introduced to my `$PATH` variable.

What i found out ('believe') so far:
in `/etc/login.defs` the first definition of `$PATH` occurs. By default the `games` folders are added here, but they remain persistent when i remove them at this place. I have the following lines in there:

```
# *REQUIRED*  The default PATH settings, for superuser and normal users.
# (they are minimal, add the rest in the shell startup files)
ENV_SUPATH      PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
# ENV_PATH      PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
ENV_PATH        PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin # note i removed games here
```

then there is `/etc/environment` which i am not yet sure when it comes into play and how it relates to `logins.defs`. It reads

```
~$ cat /etc/environment
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
```

then, as nicely presented in the answers to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415403/whats-the-difference-between-bashrc-bash-profile-and-environment) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37676849/where-is-path-variable-set-in-ubuntu) question, there are `~/.profile` and `~/.bashrc`, both of which i control very well. The latter contains the two lines

```
PATH=${PATH/":/usr/games"/""} # remove games from $PATH
PATH=${PATH/":/usr/local/games"/""}
```

when out-commented, the two games folders appear in my `$PATH`. So, where do these two folders come from? what places are parsed where the `$Path` variable is modified on startup?

Comment: ```/etc/profile```

Answer (score 2):

By default, `/etc/environment`, which is read at login, includes both `/usr/games` and `/usr/local/games`. So it looks like you edited that file also, which ought to be sufficient to drop those directories. It's unclear to me why you would need to involve `~/.profile` and/or `~/.bashrc` for the purpose.

*Edit:*

The above is based on how it works on standard Ubuntu. It's possible that the WSL default setup is slightly different.

Comment: i included `~/.profile` and `~/.bashrc` here because they seem to be referenced in most "how to add folder to `$PATH`"-tutorials.

Comment: @Dr-Nuke: Fair enough. Given the info you gave, I can't tell how the games folders are added on your system.